# How can I extract groups on Nifi Regexpr?

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

I have an Nifi application made to extract some text from a csv text.

This text has this form:

The result is: Application1:2323,Application2:2432,Application3:3421

The things that are relevant are Application1, and its value, Application2,and its value...

So I have put on an extractText processor this regexp:

(Application[\d]*):([\d]*)

But this gives me a lot of groups of regexpr, that I dont know how to extract them.

How can I get the regexpr groups?

Comment: It looks like the groups are accessible via attributes like `regex.1`, `regex.2` if your regex is set to an attribute called `regex`.

Comment: This is possible in Apache Nifi?

Answer (score 0):

Since is in csv format, why don't you create groups using the csv comma.

**Example:**
for

```
Application1:2323,Application2:2432,Application3:3421
```

**regex to user**

```
([^,]*?),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

**Your Flow :**
IncomingData -> Maybe Split -> ExtractText -> Process Attributes

**This is your Data:**

[image]

**ExtractText - see the apps attribute**

[image]

**and the output**

[image]

**Your can further transform this attributes after.**

Comment: Thanks, but how do you use replaceText to extract all the variables but only using one processor?